# Remove all xml messages with certain content from log file

Tags: xml, regex

From a system I receive errorlogs for messages that couldn't be exchanged between two components.
This log contains all kinds of messages, and I want to remove one particular type of message using regular expressions (directly in Notepad++).

All messages have the same layout, only the part between  brackets can contain different types. In case the text "type1206" is placed somewhere between the  brackets, I want to filter that complete message, starting from the date/timestamp 20141011.... to . See example message below:

```
20141022.125854.816
<env:Envelope xmlns:env">
<env:Header>
    <node>Encap.150</node>
    <type>error</type>
    <dateAndTime>2014-10-22T10:58:54.815Z</dateAndTime>
    <comment>Exception while processing message</comment>
    <exception>
        <message>No message layout configured for message of type1206. (Message: '02001410221058548094000004b6')</message>
        <class>java.lang.Exception</class>
    </exception>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
    <env:Envelope>
        <env:Header>
            <node>ConvertingFixedStringSplitter.PLCxx</node>
            <type>data</type>
            <msgRecvTime>1.413975534815E12</msgRecvTime>
            <dateAndTime>2014-10-22T10:58:54.815Z</dateAndTime>
            <umid>TcpipFromPLC.PLCxx_87305_2014-10-22T10:58:54.815Z</umid>
                </env:Header>
        <env:Body>02001410221058548094000004b6000000000000007f0</env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
</env:Body>
```

'

All other messages should not be deleted. I don't have any problems finding the type1206, but "selecting" the complete message around it.

Comment: What language do you want to use?

Comment: I see i totally forgot to mention in my message :)
I think to keep it as easy as possible, and use regular expressions just directly from notepad++, as the changes do not need to be saved. It's only for viewing / troubleshooting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The regexpo should look like :

```
/<env:Envelope xmlns:env">.*type1206.*<\/env:Body>.*<\/env:Envelope>.*<\/env:Envelope>/Ugs
```

U for Ungreedy, s for "multiline"

But only you knows exactly where to start and when to end what you want to remove :)

http://regex101.com/r/tC7dU4/3

Comment: Thanks, this almost works! A case in which it doesn't work, is when there is a message with e.g. type 1201 in between. The <envelope start tag from that message is taken, it keeps searching untill it finds the 1206 (in a next message), and thus selects multiple messages in that case.

Comment: yes you need to adapt to your full XML structure, and the exact way a message starts and ends, to adapt the regexp...

Comment: Well, the problem is that every message starts and ends exactly the same, only the "type" is different.

Comment: It's not a problem. If every message starts and ends the same way then you can define the exact regexp.
In your example there are syntax errors ( in <env:Envelope xmlns:env"> for example) and a </env:Envelope> missing at the end so it's not enough to write the exact regexp